# Merging SQL tables keeping the latest rows

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have an existing SQL table a bit like this

| Question | Answer | AnsWhen | AnsWho |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Q1 | Red | 2022-03-01 | Rod |
| Q1 | Green | 2022-03-20 | Freddie |
| Q2 | Blue | 2022-04-05 | Jane |
| Q2 | Yellow | 2022-04-01 | Rod |
| Q3 | Green | 2022-04-05 | Jane |
| Q3 | Green | 2022-04-04 | Rod |
| Q3 | Green | 2022-04-06 | Freddie |

I need to remove duplicate questions and only keep the latest data, so the finished table would look like

| Question | Answer | AnsWhen | AnsWho |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Q1 | Green | 2022-03-20 | Freddie |
| Q2 | Blue | 2022-04-05 | Jane |
| Q3 | Green | 2022-04-06 | Freddie |

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: What happens if you have two answers for the same question on the same day? Sounds like you also want a timestamp column.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. The database is SQL Express.  The actual table is about 20 columns wide and the AnsWhen is a datetime value to fractions of a second.  I just created the above table to demonstrate the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database support it, `ROW_NUMBER` can be used here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Question ORDER BY AnsWhen DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT Question, Answer, AnsWhen, AnsWho
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested, something like so.

```
with cteQuestions
as
(
select a.question,max(a.AnsWhen) as MAX_DATE
from tblAnswers as a
group by a.question
)
select q.question,a.answer,q.MAX_DATE,a.AnsWho
from cteQuestions as q
left join tblAnswers as a on q.question=a.question and q.max_date=a.AnsWhen
```